# Flutter - Waiting for an asynchronous function call return from multiple synchronous function calls

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I have an async function which is called multiple times synchoronusly.

```
List response = await Future.wait([future, future])
```

Inside, it popups a form and waiting for it to be submitted or cancelled.

```
var val = await Navigator.push(
  context, 
  MaterialPageRoute(builder : (context) => const TheForm())
);
```

The first served `Future` will popup the form first and waiting for the return. No problem with that. But I want the second `Future` to check first if the form is already popped up. If it is, it just waiting for it to conclude and receive the same returned value.

I'm aware that receiving same function return from two calls sounds crazy and impossible. I'm just looking for a way to hold the second `Future` call on and trigger to conclude it from somewhere else.

Kindly tell me what I was missing and I'll provide the required information.

Comment: post the minimal runnable code to test it

Comment: @pskink tq for the reply. ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to use `ValueNotifier`'s. Unfortunately `ValueNotifier.addListener()` only accept a `VoidCallback`. As for now, this is my solution. Still looking for a better way to replace the loop.

```
  Future future() async{
    if(ison) await Future.doWhile(() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      return ison;
    });
    else{
      ison = true;
      result = ... //Popup form
      ison = false;
    }
    return await result;
  }
```

Comment: As I showed in my answer, you should just `await` an existing `Future` instead of polling in a loop.  I've updated my answer slightly to better fit what I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to coalesce multiple calls to an asynchronous operation.  Make your asynchronous operation cache the `Future` it returns, and make subsequent calls return that `Future` directly.  For example:

```dart
Future<Result>? _pending;

Future<Result> foo() {
   if (_pending != null) {
     return _pending!;
   }

   Future<Result> doActualWork() async {
     // Stuff goes here (such as showing a form).
   }

   return _pending = doActualWork();
}
```

Now, no matter how many times you do `await foo();`, `doActualWork()` will be executed at most once. (As pskink noted in a comment, [`AsyncMemoizer`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/AsyncMemoizer-class.html) from `package:async` can do this for you.)

If you instead want to allow `doActualWork()` to be executed multiple times and just to coalesce concurrent calls, then make `doActualWork` set `_pending = null;` immediately before it `return`s.

Comment: isn't that what [AsyncMemoizer](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/AsyncMemoizer-class.html) is doing actually?

Comment: @pskink Ah, yes, I had forgotten about that.